# How to Show Message before Form is Loaded in WinCE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How I can show any message before the main form is loaded in Windows CE??
(I work in WinCE)

Comment: Please explain how you want to "show" the "message"

Answer (score 1):

In your main function in program.cs, before the main form is created, you could call a message box with MessageBox.show, specifically:  (this example if from a winforms app, so the Application.EnableVisualStyles() probably doesn't apply, but it should work the same)

```
 static void main()
 {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MessageBox.Show("Here is your message");
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
 }
```

Comment: thank's for the help, i have the Main form that load database and fill comboBox whit database. it take for 10-15 second. i need that in this time will be any message.  how can i do it ? (i dont want MessageBox)

Comment: How are you planning on displaying the message?  What are you looking to do?  Create a splash page while you main form loads?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a splash screen on WinCe, you should be able to create a second form and show that while you are doing your database interaction then close that form and load your main form once that is completed

Comment: You can open the .png file do a system ticks for 10-15 sec then close the .png and show the form

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing it would be to add a delegate for the form's Load event and do a [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) in that delegate.  I haven't used WinCE, though, so I don't know if it would work there, though.